# Microsoft Graph | combining both search and filtering on one API call

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am working on integrating MS Graph inside my application and one scenario I have to list files from OneDrive with search, filtering and sorting functionality but the API listed on the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/filtering-results?view=odsp-graph-online#filterable-properties) doesn't work

Currently I am calling 3 APIs to make search, filtering and sorting work together.

**Note:** when I tried the API listed on the official docs I got this error [image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that Microsoft Graph API doesn't support filtering on files or folder directly.
Try to use the Onedrive Rest Api like this

```
GET: drive/root/children?filter=folder+ne+null
```